# CTE with additional date lookup returning NULL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert a hierarchy from a currency holiday table to select the specific date occurrence for 2022.

Source table:

| hol_ccy | holiday | date_type | hol_dt | hol_day_no | calloc_id | base_hol_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | Good Friday | Date | 2022-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 9159 | NULL |
| CHF | Good Friday | Date | 2012-04-06 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 9169 | NULL |
| CHF | Easter Monday | Ordinal Based | 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 9188 | 9169 |
| CHF | Easter | Ordinal Based | 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 9189 | 9169 |
| CHF | Ascension | Ordinal Based | 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 39 | 9190 | 9189 |
| CHF | Whit Monday | Ordinal Based | 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 | 50 | 9191 | 9189 |

```sql
    CREATE TABLE MyTable (
      "hol_ccy" VARCHAR(3),
      "holiday" VARCHAR(13),
      "date_type" VARCHAR(13),
      "hol_dt" datetime,
      "hol_day_no" INTEGER,
      "calloc_id" INTEGER,
      "base_hol_id" INTEGER
    );
    
    INSERT INTO MyTable
      ("hol_ccy", "holiday", "date_type", "hol_dt", "hol_day_no", "calloc_id", "base_hol_id")
    VALUES
      ('CHF', 'Good Friday', 'Date', '2022-04-15 00:00:00.000', '0', '9159',null),
      ('CHF', 'Good Friday', 'Date', '2012-04-06 00:00:00.000', '0', '9169',null),
      ('CHF', 'Easter Monday', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '3', '9188',9169),
      ('CHF', 'Easter', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '2', '9189',9169),
      ('CHF', 'Ascension', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '39', '9190',9189),
      ('CHF', 'Whit Monday', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '50', '9191',9189);
```

Annoyingly the base holiday for Easter Monday and Easter are tied to the first occurrence of Good Friday in the table *(I can't change this unfortunately)* I need **this** years (2022) occurrence of Good Friday (*Working*). I am however not returning the expected calculated values for Ascension and Whit Monday.

Desired Output:

| CCY | HOLIDAY | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | Easter Monday | 2022-04-18 00:00:00.000 |
| CHF | Easter | 2022-04-17 00:00:00.000 |
| CHF | Ascension | 2022-05-26 00:00:00.000 |
| CHF | Whit Monday | 2022-06-06 00:00:00.000 |

My Attempt: *with the help from this community*

```
    WITH cte
     AS (SELECT a.hol_ccy,
                a.holiday,
                a.hol_dt,
                a.hol_day_no,
                a.calloc_id,
                a.date_type
         FROM   MyTable a
         WHERE  a.base_hol_id IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT b.hol_ccy,
                b.holiday,
                Dateadd(day, b.hol_day_no, (SELECT c.hol_dt
                                            FROM   MyTable c
                                            WHERE  c.holiday = cte.holiday
                                                   AND c.hol_ccy = cte.hol_ccy
                                                   AND Year(c.hol_dt) = 2022)),
                b.hol_day_no,
                b.calloc_id,
                b.date_type
         FROM   MyTable b
                JOIN cte
                  ON cte.calloc_id = b.base_hol_id)
SELECT t.hol_ccy,
       t.holiday,
       t.hol_dt
FROM   cte t
WHERE  t.hol_ccy = 'CHF'
AND    t.date_type = 'Ordinal Based'
```

The Output of my Attempt: Easter and Easter Monday are correct

| CCY | HOLIDAY | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | Easter Monday | 2022-04-18 00:00:00.000 |
| CHF | Easter | 2022-04-17 00:00:00.000 |
| CHF | Ascension | NULL |
| CHF | Whit Monday | NULL |

Do I need to nest an additional CTE to look for the 2022 Ascension and Whit Monday calculated values?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you - edited for clarity: I see now this may have been confusing - I am looking to return the Ascension and Whit Monday calculated dates in addition to the Easter Monday and Easter dates. I am fine with not returning Good Friday.

Comment: None of your rows relate to the 2022 Good Friday; that's why your hierachy isn't working. Seems you need to `INSERT` the related rows with a value of `9159` for `base_hol_id`.

Comment: Though, I will admit, I would suggest you try to switch to a "traditional" calendar/holiday table, where you just store the values for the holiday's in each year, rather than using this hierarchical method.

Comment: @lptr the answer section is *below* the comments. Random links to fiddles with no context are **not** helpful.

Comment: Also, @lptr , the dates in your random fiddle are for 2012, *not* 2022.

Comment: @lptr Nice solution! - Please post as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr)'s comment. I am posting it as a community answer as they did not post it as an answer upon request. *lptr, if you chose to post your own answer, please flag this for removal or comment.*

> for a single hierarchy of dates (not repeating per year)..
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TABLE MyTable (
>   "hol_ccy" VARCHAR(3),
>   "holiday" VARCHAR(13),
>   "date_type" VARCHAR(13),
>   "hol_dt" datetime,
>   "hol_day_no" INTEGER,
>   "calloc_id" INTEGER,
>   "base_hol_id" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO MyTable
>   ("hol_ccy", "holiday", "date_type", "hol_dt", "hol_day_no", "calloc_id", "base_hol_id")
> VALUES
>   ('CHF', 'Good Friday', 'Date', '2022-04-15 00:00:00.000', '0', '9159',null),
>   ('CHF', 'Good Friday', 'Date', '2012-04-06 00:00:00.000', '0', '9169',null),
>   ('CHF', 'Easter Monday', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '3', '9188',9169),
>   ('CHF', 'Easter', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '2', '9189',9169),
>   ('CHF', 'Ascension', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '39', '9190',9189),
>   ('CHF', 'Whit Monday', 'Ordinal Based', '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', '50', '9191',9189);
> GO
> WITH cte
>      AS (SELECT a.hol_ccy,
>                 a.holiday,
>                 a.hol_dt,
>                 a.hol_day_no,
>                 a.calloc_id,
>                 a.date_type,
>                 a.base_hol_id,
>               --  a.hol_dt as thedate
>                 max(case when year(hol_dt)=2022 then hol_dt end) over(partition by hol_ccy,holiday) as thedate
>          FROM   MyTable a
>          WHERE  a.base_hol_id IS NULL
>          UNION ALL
>          SELECT b.hol_ccy,
>                 b.holiday,
>                 b.hol_dt,
>                 b.hol_day_no,
>                 b.calloc_id,
>                 b.date_type,
>                 b.base_hol_id,
>                 Dateadd(day, b.hol_day_no, cte.thedate) as thedate
>                 --case b.date_type when 'date' then b.hol_dt else Dateadd(day, b.hol_day_no, cte.thedate) end
>          FROM   MyTable b
>                 JOIN cte
>                   ON cte.calloc_id = b.base_hol_id)
> SELECT t.hol_ccy,
>        t.holiday,
>        t.hol_dt, t.calloc_id, t.base_hol_id, t.date_type, t.thedate
> FROM   cte t
> WHERE  t.hol_ccy = 'CHF'
> --AND    t.date_type = 'Ordinal Based'
> ```
>
> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c0f713eeddd4ae7545c232aa5aaac8b)